# check several booleans at once in ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean

I have several records for an object (not all of them) that I have to check whether they're true or false, to mark another record true or false. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
step_finished = object.one == true &&  object.two == true && object.three == true &&  object.four == true
```

I'm sure there must be a better way but I haven't been able to find it. I have another step with 20 values to check, so if you know a more efficient way check this, please help!

Thanks!

Comment: `[object.one, object.two, object.three, object.four].all?` [all? method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F)

Comment: Are your record in an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to test for `== true`; it is enough to simply test the "truthiness" of something. Anything that is not `nil` or `false` will evaluate to `true` in a *boolean context*. So it is sufficient to do:

```
step_finished = object.one && object.two && object.three && object.four
```

You can also use `all?`:

```
step_finished = [object.one, object.two, object.three, object.four].all?
```

Comment: The "thing" you test is the truthiness of an object. An object is truthy if it is not falsey. The only objects that are falsey are `false` and `nil`, all others are truthy (including `0`, an empty string, an empty array, ...).

Comment: @HolgerJust fair point, I've edited the explanation. Let me know if you think it would benefit from any further clarification.

Answer (score 4):

any object in ruby return value like `true, false, nil` -> `== true` therefore unnecessary

put you record to array and check 

`[object.one, object.two, object.three, object.four].all?` [all? method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F)

Comment: brilliant. There are solutions for everything in Ruby. Thanks a lot Monk_Code

Comment: you this method can pass `&block` to check some thing

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you could use `reduce` like this:

```
[object.one, object.two, object.three, object.four].reduce(:&)
```

to check if all elements in array are `true`.
And you could use this:

```
[object.one, object.two, object.three, object.four].reduce(:|)
```

to check if at least one from them is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
step_finished = [:one, :two, :three, :four].all? { |attr| object.send(attr) }
```